# SonataAdminBundle, How can I display list of a ManyToOne in the show view?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

Using the SonataAdminBundle on a Symfony Application, I'm trying to display a set of previously stored records of a child entity in the *SHOW* view

The application is about logging visit details for a visit, where I have a visit entity with a visitDetail property set as OneToMany:

**Entity\Visit.php**

```
/**  
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\VisitDetail  
 *  
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\VisitDetail", cascade={"all"}, mappedBy="visitVisit", orphanRemoval=true ))  
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"visitDetailId" = "ASC"})  
 */ 

  private $visitDetail;
```

And in the VisitDetail Entity I have a the properties like: Type, Date, Comments etc..

As for the Sonata Side I have:

**VisitAdmin.php**

```
   // Fields to be shown on show action
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper->add('visitDetail')
    }
```

How can I display all the records in visitDetail that belongs to the visit?

Comment: Are you sure you want sonata?

Comment: @Rienk yes, why? any other better option other than custom make all the  CRUD classes and UI?

Comment: I tried it once and did not really like it, but just asking :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to create a `__toString()` function in your VisitDetail entity, where you return the properties you want to show of course.